# PHP 7.2 Support Patches for Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, php-7, php-7.2

Magento released a bunch of patches today for M1 compatibility with PHP7.
This is great news as PHP7 is so much faster.
Before we go ahead and apply them, I would like to know if anyone encountered any compatibility problems or bugs after applying the patch?

We had been using [Inchoo's PHP 7 compatibility extension for Magento 1](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7)  but it's currently deprecated because of the new Magento Patches.

Comment: Are there any news about this?

Comment: The couple instances that we tested this on ran smoothly